# Listbox resizing automatically, button doesn't

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I've got a `ListBox` with `CheckBoxes` in it which resizes automatically when I resize the Window.
I found the `CheckedListBox XAML` code on StackOverflow I think and I didn't modify it, and I'd like the same thing for all the UI elements.

I've read something about setting `Anchors`. As I already said, I didn't do anything to the XAML code, neither did I set any `Anchors`?

Is there anything in the XAML code which I'm not seeing which is responsible for the resizing?

```
         <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,28,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238" />
    <Label Content="Profilname" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding datasource}" Margin="12,57,12,41"  Name="checkedListBox1" Opacity="0.7">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Item}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="save" Margin="12,302,12,12" Name="button3" Click="button3_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should post its container too

Comment: Edited it. I guess the container is the grid here, right? I noticed, the listbox doesn't resize automatically in a tabcontrol

Comment: It is unclear to me what the problem is here. Also, there's no such thing as an `Anchor` in WPF. That is a Winforms concept. Take a look a Layout in WPF. You should not use a Grid and `Margin` for these kind of layouts.

Comment: My question is: why is the listbox resizing and the button isn't?

Comment: Your margins seem sketchy, don't have time to put it in example and try it, but you need to set Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached properties I believe and define your rows/columns using Grid.RowDefinitions and the equivelant for cols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it like a Canvas, but you are using a Grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Profilname" Name="label1" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Name="textBox1" Grid.Row="1" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding datasource}" Name="checkedListBox1" Grid.Row="2" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Item}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Content="save" Name="button3" Click="button3_Click"  Grid.Row="3" />
</Grid>
```

See now everything resizes.

You can add margin and padding now as desired for styling.